# Update .Net version caused System assembly not found problem

Tags: .net, azure, version

I'm trying to update my .NET version to 4.8 within CoreXT framework.

However after I updated 
`<package id="NET_Framework_48_TargetingPack" version="4.8.3761" allMacros="true" />`
in corext.config file,

All System related assembly can not be found. Like System, System.Data and so on.

May I ask do I missed any other reference version to update? Or how can I set up the System assembly location successfully?
Thanks.

Comment: Any progress now? If it helps you, you could accept it as answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you retarget a project to a different version of the .NET Framework, your references may not resolve properly in some cases. Explicit fully qualified references to assemblies often cause this issue, but you can **resolve it by removing the references** that do not resolve and then **adding them back to the project**. As an alternative, you can **edit the project file to replace the references**. Refer to this article to [Troubleshoot .NET Framework targeting errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/troubleshooting-dotnet-framework-targeting-errors?view=vs-2019).

First, you remove references of the following form:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel, Version=3.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089, processorArchitecture=MSIL" />
```

Then you replace them with the simple form:

```
<Reference Include="System.ServiceModel" />
```

**Note**: After you close and reopen your project, you should also rebuild it to ensure that all references resolve correctly.